# Sequence of CAAnimations - layer returns to initial position between subsequent calls

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm trying to create an endless animation of layer rotating slightly to the left, then slightly to the right and back. So I'm animating 10 degress to the left, then 20 to the right, then 10 to the left again.
It works great on simulator, but on device the layer "shivers". It appears like it returns to its previous state every time before it starts next animation. 
I've read that using

animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

helps in such cases, but if I use those, the whole layers just freezes in place after first animation and never moves anywhere.

So here's the code:

```
- (void) initAnimations {
    float baseValue = [[self.layer valueForKey:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

    rotateLeft = [[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] retain];
    rotateLeft.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:baseValue];
    rotateLeft.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:baseValue - DegreesToRadians(10.0f)];
    rotateLeft.duration = 0.4f;
    rotateLeft.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    rotateLeft.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotateLeft.repeatCount = 0;
    rotateLeft.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    rotateLeft.delegate = self;

    rotateRight = [[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] retain];
    rotateRight.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:baseValue - DegreesToRadians(10.0f)];
    rotateRight.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:baseValue + DegreesToRadians(10.0f)];
    rotateRight.duration = 0.6f;
    rotateRight.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    rotateRight.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotateRight.repeatCount = 0;
    rotateRight.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    rotateRight.delegate = self;

    rotateRestore = [[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] retain];
    rotateRestore.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:baseValue + DegreesToRadians(10.0f)];
    rotateRestore.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:baseValue];
    rotateRestore.duration = 0.3f;
    rotateRestore.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    rotateRestore.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotateRestore.repeatCount = 0;
    rotateRestore.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    rotateRestore.delegate = self;
}

- (void) beginAnimations {
    if (animationsRunning)
        return;

    [self.layer addAnimation:rotateLeft forKey:nil];
}

- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation {

}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    [self.layer removeAllAnimations];
    if (self.superview == nil) {
        rotateLeft.delegate = nil;
        rotateRight.delegate = nil;
        rotateRestore.delegate = nil;
        return;
    }

    float dt;
    if (step == 0) {
        dt = 0.7f + (float)(random() % 3) / 10.0f;
    } else {
        dt = 0.4f + (float)(random() % 3) / 10.0f;
    }

    CABasicAnimation* nextAnimation = nil;
    if (step == 0) {
        nextAnimation = rotateRight;
    } else if (step == 1) {
        nextAnimation = rotateRestore;
    } else if (step == 2) {
        nextAnimation = rotateLeft;
    }

    nextAnimation.duration = dt;
    [self.layer addAnimation:nextAnimation forKey:nil];

    step++;
    if (step == 3)
        step = 0;
}
```

Why isn't it working? I think I've already tried all removedOnCompletion / fillMode combinations and nothing seems to help =(

Comment: Wouldn't UIView animations be easier?

Comment: How are you applying the animations to occur one after the other and then repeating? I might be able to help. But I agree with tc's comment, UIView animations would definitely be easier in this case unless you have a different reason for using CAAnimations.

Comment: I've tried using CALayer instead of UIView animations because I was hoping it would work faster. Unfortunately, neither uiview nor calayer animations weren't fast enough. In fact, I couldn't get more then 15 fps when animating just 9 views. So I had to rewrite the whole thing in opengl.